# Cannot run riemann interactivity

Tags: clojure, riemann

Hello I am taking a class for college and I have ran into an error that states I have an unmatched delimiter. Does this error mean that my config file for riemann has an error?

[image: error message]

Comment: Yes, in fact, your error is on line 29, column 46... see it in the message?

Comment: I see it now and I get it thanks so much.